# Cannot Verify Ethereum ERC20 token

Tags: token, ethereum, erc20

I have successfully deployed an `Ethereum ERC20` token using the code on:

> https://www.ethereum.org/token

Now came to the stage when we need to verify the contract, which I am unable to.

I have compared input bytecode with bytecode in my Wallet and they are same so I am sure using correct code, also I used `pragma solidity 0.4.16` in my code so used `v0.4.16+commit.d7661dd9` and `optimization=1`.

Please help!

Comment: Might be better to use Ethereum.stackexchange

Comment: Yes I did but no response.

Comment: Maybe be more specific? What kind of verification are you trying to do? If the bytecode matches, what’s the problem? Do you see your contract on Etherscan?